# designing a web based multi-branch system

Tags: php, wan

is it possible to design a multibranch web-based system and using the web(internet) as ur platform?

what i mean is that it wont be necessary to have a specialized WAN for the company, but just use a high speed intenet connection?

thnx,

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. I guess you're talking about a web app that is specific to a few branches. You could easy set rules that only allow the app to be accessed from a few site specific IP addresses. All you need is a static IP.

Comment: And if those could not be provided you could just fall back to simple password protection

Comment: what about matters concerning speed and security? and please is there any material on the net i could refer to concerning this matter. thnx i appreciate

Comment: Speed shouldn't be too much of an issue. If your push commercially sensitive material about, get a decent signed SSL certificate and all is good.